# NSThread to stop process

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsthread

I am using a navigation base application. When I go to next view or back to the previous view, the thread does not stop. Can someone give me a solution for stopping the thread when switching between views? When I switch to next or previous, the application crashes. I use thread like this for downloading the image

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AppDeleget=  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ProcessView *Process=[[ProcessView alloc] init];
    [Process SearchProperty:AppDeleget.PropertyURL page:AppDeleget.Page];
    [Process release];
    for(NSDictionary *status in AppDeleget.statuses)
    {       

        NSMutableString *pic_string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[status objectForKey:@"picture"]];  

        if([pic_string isEqualToString:@""])
        {

            [ListPhotos addObject:@"NA"];

        }
        else
        {

            NSString *str= [[[status objectForKey:@"picture"] valueForKey:@"url"] objectAtIndex:0];
            [ListPhotos addObject:str];  


        }
    }
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(LoadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

    [AppDeleget.MyProgressView stopAnimating];
    [AppDeleget.Progress removeFromSuperview];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
-(void)LoadImage
{
    for(int x=0;x<[ListPhotos count];x++)
    {   
        NSData *imageData =[ListPhotos objectAtIndex:x]; 
        id path = imageData;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSLog(@"%@",url);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:NO];

    }

}
-(void)downloadDone:(UIImage*)img {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0];

    if(img == nil)
    {
        TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        cell.myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"No_image.png"];
        ++count;
        [TableView reloadData]; 

    }
    else
    {
        TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        cell.myImageView.image=img;
        ++count;
        [TableView reloadData]; 
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a thread which is being executed using the instance method `cancel`

```
[yourThread cancel];
```

Or you can use `exit`

```
[yourThread exit];
```

which will terminate the thread

Comment: You mean control doesnt comes out of loadImage function?

Comment: when use this at that time the simulator is hang

Answer (score 0):

You have started the thread in `viewWillAppear`, hence it will get called when you switch between your view controllers. If you want to execute your thread only once, then try putting it in `viewDidLoad`.